# jQuery - RegEx working bizarrely

Tags: javascript, regex

I am very new to RegExp. Here is my problem. I have an input value. I apply a RegExp "rule" to that input value. The rule is starts with the input value and is not case sensitive. Lets take an example. My reference string is `Paris (75018)` and my input value is `Pari`. In that scenario everything is working fine. But if the input value is `Paris (7` it is not working. In that case the "system" is telling me no match and I don't get it. It is matching! Hope someone can help. Thank you in advance for your replies. Cheers. Marc.

http://jsfiddle.net/JU8Va/

My html:

```
<input id="btn" type="submit" />​
```

My js:

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    var loc = "Paris"; //input value...
    var locRegExp = new RegExp("^" + loc, "i"); // 

    var test = "Paris (75018)"; //reference value

    if (test.match(locRegExp)) {
        alert('matches');
        }
        else {
            alert('does not match');
        }
    });​
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `(` has a special meaning in regular expressions. To get it literally, you have to escape it as `\(`. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/JU8Va/1/

```
var loc = "Paris \\(7";
var locRegExp = new RegExp("^" + loc, "i");
```

*Note that there is a double backslash; that's because backslash itself has a special meaning in literal quoted strings, so you have to escape the backslash to get it literally in the regex.*

*Also note that for literal (unquoted) regexes, you don't need to escape the backslash, just the parenthesis. For example: `test.match(/Paris \(7/)`.*

In regular expressions, an unescaped `(` means "start a capture group". Capture groups are the way you retrieve match data after running it. See here for an answer about how those work: http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

If you don't know ahead of time what `loc` will contain, you can replace all instances of parenthesis with the escaped versions, like this:

```
var locRegExp = new RegExp("^" + loc.replace(/\(/g, "\\(").replace(/\)/g, "\\)"), "i");
```

But be aware that there are many special characters besides parenthesis that you may need to test for. If you find yourself replacing a lot of characters, maybe consider trying a different approach. For example, are you just looking for a case-insensitive search that starts at the beginning of the test string? For that you don't need regular expressions, you can just do a substring search:

```
test.toLowerCase().indexOf(loc.toLowerCase()) === 0
```

Comment: Hello Ben. Thanks to take time to help me out. Is it possible to apply a rule with regexp or else to do it programmatically?

Comment: @Marc, I don't understand what you mean by a "rule".

Comment: I mean is it possible to add automatically the slashes?

Comment: Also see @pimvdb's link. That's how you would replace *all* special characters if you need to. But if you find yourself doing that, regex may not be the best solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to escape the special characters used by regex. In your example `(` is that character.

Answer (score 1):

It's because "(" is a special char and should be escaped. The escaped pattern should be:

```
Paris \(7
```